# convert list to struct

Tags: c, list, struct

I'm trying to write a process table for my forks. I've got a global table and every process has to be written into this table.

I've got the struct

```
typedef struct {
int pid;        /* Prozess ID */
char* name;     /* Prozess Name (Programm) */
char* status;   /* Status des Programms */
int check;      /* bereits abgerufen? 1 - abgerufen, 0 - nicht abgerufen */
} Pstatus;
```

Listen:

```
typedef struct liste {
  void *kopf;
  struct liste *rest;
} *Liste;
```

listeKopf:

```
void* listeKopf(Liste l) { 
  if(l==NULL)
    abbruch("listeKopf(listeLeer) undefiniert");
  return l->kopf; 
}
```

listeAnfuegen:

```
Liste listeAnfuegen(Liste l, void* element){
  Liste neu=reserviere(sizeof (struct liste));
  neu->kopf = element;
  neu->rest = l;
  return neu;
}
```

I'm writing my processes into the list using struct Pstatus. When I'm trying to read from my list I get the error: conversion to non-scalar type requested in line 284

my code is here:

http://pastebin.com/xEDvLTQk

Is somebody able to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at your code, basically on your line 284, you have this expression:

```
p = (Pstatus) listeKopf(temp);
```

the p is just the `Pstatus struct variable` and your `listeKopf(temp)` returns `(void *kopf)` which can not be assigned to a non-scaler variable( it should be assigned to a pointer).

you should change your code to look like this:

```
Pstatus *p
p =  listeKopf(temp);
```

to avoid the error you are getting and also the `cast to Pstatus` is not needed as `void *` can be assigned to any pointer type.

**Scalar types in C:**

- Arithmatic Types
- Pointer Types

I hope it helps.

Comment: okay thank you. I had tried to store it in another function and got the same error. The solution worked. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

So `Liste` is a generic list that can hold references to anything via a `void *` pointer, right? And `listeKopf` returns that pointer.

According to your definition, `Pstatus` is a struct, not a pointer to struct, so you can't convert to it from `void *`. You also shouldn't be able to access its members with the `->` operator, only with the dot `.` syntax.

(As a matter of personal taste, I prefer not to `typedef` pointer types, so that you can see whether a variable is a pointer or not by looking at the stars in the code.)

Comment: Yeah it is an generic list and listeKopf returns it. So I am not able to save my Pstatus into my List?

Comment: Yes, you can do that, of course. From the name I guess that `erzeugeProzess` creates a new process on the heap by calling `malloc` somewhere. That's a pointer of type `Pstatus *`, which you can (and should) store in the list. You can retrieve it as suggested in dreamer's answer, by making your local variable a pointer. (I guess you meant to do that anyway, juding from the arrow operators.) You will have to cast to the proper type, of course. (Or, maybe better, don't case, because conversion from `void *` to another non-constant pointer type is implicit.)

Comment: Also take care not to print the `Pstatus * ` pointer with `%s`. C is not Python and it will think that the pointer is to `char`, which it isn't. You can print `%s` `p->name`, though, if it is properly initialised and not `NULL`.